# What is the proper way to load Raku modules using rakudo-star?

Tags: raku, rakudo-star

I have the following project

```
$ tree
.
├── lib
│   └── MyModule.raku
└── main.raku

$ cat lib/MyModule.raku
use v6;
unit module MyModule;
sub hello { say 'hello' }

$ cat lib/main.raku
use v6;
use MyModule;
MyModule.hello();
```

I would like to run main.raku using the latest `rakudo-star` [image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rakudo-star).  However the following occurs

```
$ docker run -i --rm -u $(id -u) \
--workdir /work \
--volume  $PWD:/work \
--entrypoint bash \
rakudo-star perl6 -I ./lib main.raku
===SORRY!===
Could not find MyModule at line 3 in:
    file#/work/lib
    inst#/.perl6
    inst#/usr/share/perl6/site
    inst#/usr/share/perl6/vendor
    inst#/usr/share/perl6
    ap#
    nqp#
    perl5#
```

I have also tried inserting `use lib '/work/lib'` before `use MyModule` in main.raku with the same result.

Comment: The way you show it here, main.raku is not in lib, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems.

1. Modules don't end with `.raku`. They end with `.rakumod` or `.pm6` (for now).
   (Technically after you install, it doesn't actually matter what the extension is as long as you have it properly declared in `META6.json`.)
2. Subroutines are lexically scoped by default (`my`), and are also not exported by default.
   So there is no way to access `hello()` outside of the module it is defined in.
3. Modules don't have methods, so you can't call `hello` as a method.
   Even if they did have methods they wouldn't start with the `sub` keyword.

---

You can globally scope the subroutine with `our`:

`lib/MyModule.rakumod`

```raku
use v6.d;
unit module MyModule;

our sub hello () { say 'hello' }
#^
# \
#  globally scoped
```

`main.raku`

```raku
use v6.d;
# use lib './lib';
use module MyModule;

MyModule::hello();
#       ^^
#        \
#         namespace delimiter
```

---

You could export it instead:

`lib/MyModule.rakumod`

```raku
use v6.d;
unit MyModule;

#             mark for export
#            v-------v
sub hello () is export {
    say 'hello'
}
```

`main.raku`

```raku
use v6.d;
# use lib './lib';
use MyModule;

hello();
```

In addition to [`is export`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/is%20export), there are [other more fine grained ways to export](https://docs.raku.org/language/modules#Exporting_and_selective_importing).

I would recommend that if you are going to export, that you also make it global with `our`.  That way if someone uses your module, but doesn't want to import your subs; they still have access to them.

Comment: Thank you, my syntax/grammar was totally screwed up, but I wasn't even worrying about until I could get the module to to import. Thank you for the thorough answer 

Answer (score 5):

New Raku versions uses the `.rakumod` as file extension for modules. The older `.pm6` extension is still supported. More information regarding the new file extensions can be found in the [Path-to-Raku](https://github.com/Raku/problem-solving/blob/master/solutions/language/Path-to-Raku.md) ticket. More information about modules is available in the [raku documentation](https://docs.raku.org/language/modules).

Comment: Changing the filename does not appear make any difference.

Comment: Exact the same error message? After change to MyModule.rakumod I get the following message `No such method 'hello' for invocant of type 'MyModule'..`

Comment: Exact same, unfortunately 

Comment: Hmm, can you try to use .pm6 as module file extension?

Comment: That one worked! And by worked I mean gave me a different error, but that means the module was imported  Is there any documentation related to this?